# Testing taskqueues locally on google app engine using dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

My app engine app has 2 queues. A worker from the first queue initiates several workers in the second queue and wait for them to complete and consolidate.

This works fine when I deploy it, but it <s>doesn't work</s> never spawns the tasks in the second queue when testing locally. It gets stuck while waiting for it to update (see code below). The reason seems to be that dev_appserver is single threaded and does not launch services in the background.

This is really slowing down my development since I have to deploy to the cloud to test anything.

Any ways around this?

Edit: Adding the (sort of) pseudo code below. Again, this works perfectly fine in the cloud because I have a 10 minute time limit to complete the task and each `BigTask` takes not more than 30-40 seconds to complete.

#### Queue 1 Worker

```
class BigTask(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def do_stuff(self):
    #do something here
    small_task1 = taskqueue.add(...)
    small_task2 = taskqueue.add(...)
    small_task3 = taskqueue.add(...)
    small_task4 = taskqueue.add(...)
    # Create ndb entries for all small tasks
    
    while True:
      time.sleep(2)
      # Check if ndb entry updated for all small_tasks
      if status == 'Completed': #for all
        break
    
    add_results(...) # of all tasks here
    
    # Update ndb entry for big_task
    # done
```

#### Queue 2 Worker

```
class SmallTask(webapp2.RequestHandler): 
  def do_stuff(self):
    # Do processing
    # Update ndb entry
    # done
```

Comment: Push queues work just fine for me, you may be missing something. Details?

Comment: @DanCornilescu - Yup, I'm using push queues. I believe the main reason is because the workers in one queue are launching workers in the other queue, sleeping, and waiting for the workers in the other queue to complete and then aggregate the values. So my new task command is not the last statement in the handler. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: sleeping in GAE apps is generally not a good idea. Code?

Comment: Added the code. Hmm, do you recommend I remove the sleep and create a third pull queue which finalises the data? I thought about it, but seemed to be overcomplicating it.

Comment: Instead of sleeping you could enqueue a delayed BigTask to check for status for all smaller tasks, do the `add_results(...)` stuff if they completed or re-queue itself (delayed) to re-check later on. This way you could use a single queue for all tasks.

Comment: Anyways, what "doesn't work" means exactly?

Comment: Updated the question to clarify what doesn't work, thanks for pointing that out! Hmm, that's an interesting suggestion. By 'delayed' I'm assuming you mean give it a rate of 30/m so that it (approx) runs once every 2 seconds?

Comment: Ah sorry, I think you meant to use the `countdown` field. That's an idea, let me look into this, thanks!

Comment: @DanCornilescu - Perfect! It works on local as well now. Will save me a lot of time in develoment. If you could put your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally sleeping in GAE app code is not a good idea - wasting instance uptime, increasing request latency, risk of exceeding the request deadline etc.

You can achieve the same functionality by enqueuing a delayed BigTask (using the `countdown` option) which would check the status for all smaller tasks, do the `add_results(...)` stuff if they completed or, if not, re-queue itself (again delayed) to re-check later on.

As a side effect you could even use the same task queue for both kind of tasks (if that's inline with your app requirements, of course).

Comment: Yup, I've used the same queue and added an additional param to see if it's waiting to join the tasks from the other queue.